# Trouble with Google Maps API v3 - Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've forgotten everything I learned in Javascript, so I started a project to remember some things. But I had a problem:

This is my code in Javascript:

```
    var peru = new google.maps.LatLng(-9, -75);
    var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();
    function initialize() {
        var ubicacion;  
        var mapOptions = {

            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
            },
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
            },

            panControl: false,
            scaleControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,

        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                mapOptions);

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                ubicacion = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(ubicacion);
                }, function() {
                    handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
                }
            );

        } else {
            browserSupportFlag = false;
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
            if (errorFlag == true) {
                alert("No se han otorgado permisos de Geolocalización, o el servicio falló. Utilice Google Chrome para mayor compatibilidad.");
                ubicacion = peru;
                } else {
                    alert("Su navegador no soporta Geolocalización. Puede continuar de igual forma, pero le sugerimos utilizar el navegador Google Chrome.");
                    ubicacion = peru;
                }

            map.setCenter(ubicacion);
        }

        function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                    callback(request, request.status);
                }
            };

            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.send(null);
        }

        function doNothing() {}

        downloadUrl("phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat="+ubicacion.lat()+"&lng="+ubicacion.lng()+"&r=250", function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

            function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                var name = markers[i].getAttribute("nombre");
                var address = markers[i].getAttribute("direccion");

                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map,
                  position: point,

                });

                bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
            }
        });
    }
```

And my trouble is in this part:

```
            downloadUrl("phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat="+ubicacion.lat()+"&lng="+ubicacion.lng()+"&r=250", function(data) {...}
```

I want to get the latitude and logitude variables and put them into the "url" on "download Url(url,...".

Example, if my location is -9.123792,-78.517313 y want to catch this url for it: phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=-9.123792&lng=-78.517313&r=250

Also I want the radio of search be selectable... by input number or something like that.

I really don't know how I did all this, and how i'll do all I want :S

PS.: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to modify Google's [Store locator](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3). It has all the functionality you require.

Where your problem arises is you are not passing coordinates to `downloadUrl()`

In the demo the function `searchLocationsNear(center)` sends the coordinates(center) to be joined to the url before  `downloadUrl()` is called.

I would advise you to follow the demo and ensures you understand it before modifying.

It is also advisable to use PDO in `phpsqlsearch_genxml.php` as `mysql` functions are deprecated

Comment: Oh, thanks... I'll follow every steps in the demo... but by now.. Is there any solutions for join the coordinates to the url, in my code?